# I'm using the new Places SDK in Android. The AutocompleteSupportFragment and it is requiring me to add the activity to the manifest

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I'm using the new places SDK.  My build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

My code:

```
 FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 if(mAutocompleteFragment == null) {
      mAutocompleteFragment = new AutocompleteSupportFragment();
      ft.add(R.id.places_container, mAutocompleteFragment, AutocompleteSupportFragment.class.getSimpleName());
      ft.commit();
    }

List<Place.Field> places = new ArrayList<>();
places.add(Place.Field.ID);
places.add(Place.Field.NAME);
places.add(Place.Field.ADDRESS);
mAutocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(places); //throws NPE getView() is null
```

Throws NPE, because it is trying to set view enabled in that last method and the view is null.  I suspect that the lifecycle of the fragment has not been called (onViewCreated). How would I force the lifecycle or wait for the fragment to fully cycle?

However, when I select the autocompletesupportfragment, I get a:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.activehours.debug/com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity"
        android:theme="@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay">
    </activity>
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment) made no mention of including the activity in my manifest.  Help!

**EDIT:** I got the around the NPE by extending the class as such:

```
public class AHAutocompleteSupportFragment extends AutocompleteSupportFragment 
 {

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    List<Place.Field> places = new ArrayList<>();
    places.add(Place.Field.ID);
    places.add(Place.Field.NAME);
    places.add(Place.Field.ADDRESS);
    this.setPlaceFields(places);
  }
}
```

However, I am still getting the "Activity not declared in Manifest".

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to instantiate the fragment by yourself...

```
mAutocompleteFragment = new AutocompleteSupportFragment();
```

Is there any reason you're not just using the fragment inside your existing activity?

Below is the code I'm using in my app with the new AutocompleteSupportFragment which is working just fine.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shop_search_search_area_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/shop_search_search_area_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/shop_search_search_area_margin"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="4">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/shop_search_autocomplete_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/shop_search_voice_icon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/shop_search_mic_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/shop_search_mic_size"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/shop_search_mic_margin_right"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:onClick="@{() -> model.voicePlaceSearch()}"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_24dp_gray" />
                </fragment>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

To then get a hold of it in my code I would use the same code as provided by the tutorial...

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.shop_search_autocomplete_fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

most likely you have to add an `intent-filter`, so that it will find what it expects:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity"
    android:theme="@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```